# hide the URL path of the download file using .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I took whole day making tries to get this URL hidden from the address bar or inside the PDF Document.

Here in the stack overflow there are a ton of samples, but I didn't get any of them up and running.

1. I am generating a PDF file with a [ link ] inside.
2. This link has a dynamic parameter
3. This link will generate another file to be downloaded.
4. I would like hide the URL path displayed inside the PDF file.
5. When we hover the mouse pointer over the [ link ], it displays the file's directory..

**Instead of display this in the file:**
`https://msia.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1547`

**I need to display only this**

```
https://msia.com/
```

**code**

```
$order_url = "https://msia.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=";

$url = '<a href="'.$order_url.$order_id.'"><b>Download PDF</b></a>'; 

$order_id = receives the dynamic id. Eg: 1547
```

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ([^/]+)\.example\.com.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://%1.msia.com/somepath/%1/%2 [L]
```

```
RewriteRule ^https://msia.com  https://msia.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php [NC,L]

# sends all requests from “/” to “/Site/am/index.php”
RewriteRule ^https://msia.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php$ https://msia.com
```

**With this example, I lost complete the CSS formation of the link - PDF file is not a browser to render JS.**

`<a href="http://www.google.com" id="no-link">Hyperlink</a>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
               
                $('a[href]#no-link').each(function () {
                    var href = this.href;
    
                    $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                        if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {
    
                        } else {
                            window.open(href, '_blank');
                        }
                    });
                });
    
          }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: @KJ, Thanks for the comment.

Viewing the file through Adore Reader or another pdf viewer, you can view the URL through **Tooltip**.

In the address bar when hovering over the link, you can see the url address.

Is it possible to remove the **tooltip using CSS**? I've tried it already, but I didn't use the right elements to hide the tooltip that displays the address

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would like the tooltip to display something other than the full URL?

Looking at your code, it looks like you are generating the layout of the PDF from HTML and giving this to a generator.

PDF generators don't tend to have full HTML support, but you could try to add a `title="Something that will appear in the tooltip"` attribute to your `<a>` tag.

Something like this:

`<a href="'.$order_url.$order_id.'" title="Something that displayed in the tooltip"><b>Download PDF</b></a>`

This could work, but again it does depend on the generator and their support for this attribute.

Comment: Hello @chrisbratherton, Thank you so much for the help.
I wish the situation would be solved so simple as it supposed to be, but when we hover the pointer, it display the whole directory path and through the url. I use mPDF library to generate the PDF file. I do not know still what to do.